# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getUserInformation() - PHP MySQLi

Tags: php

I have a simple login system on my project. I have a page after the user is logged in `dashboard.php` and a page for function `Auth.php`. On auth page I have this code to get user information stored into the database:

```
function getUserInformation($username,$useremail) {
        $db_handle = new DBController();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM cusers WHERE member_name = ? AND member_email = ?";
        $result = $db_handle->runQuery($query, 'ms', array($username, $useremail));
        return $result;
    }
```

Full `Auth.php` code is:

```
require "DBController.php";

class Auth {
    function getMemberByUsername($username) {
        $db_handle = new DBController();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM cusers WHERE member_name = ?";
        $result = $db_handle->runQuery($query, 's', array($username));
        return $result;
    }

    function getUserInformation($username,$useremail) {
        $db_handle = new DBController();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM cusers WHERE member_name = ? AND member_email = ?";
        $result = $db_handle->runQuery($query, 'ms', array($username, $useremail));
        return $result;
    }
    
    function getTokenByUsername($username,$expired) {
        $db_handle = new DBController();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM token_auth WHERE username = ? AND is_expired = ?";
        $result = $db_handle->runQuery($query, 'si', array($username, $expired));
        return $result;
    }
    
    function markAsExpired($tokenId) {
        $db_handle = new DBController();
        $query = "UPDATE token_auth SET is_expired = ? WHERE id = ?";
        $expired = 1;
        $result = $db_handle->update($query, 'ii', array($expired, $tokenId));
        return $result;
    }
    
    function insertToken($username, $random_password_hash, $random_selector_hash, $expiry_date) {
        $db_handle = new DBController();
        $query = "INSERT INTO token_auth (username, password_hash, selector_hash, expiry_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?)";
        $result = $db_handle->insert($query, 'ssss', array($username, $random_password_hash, $random_selector_hash, $expiry_date));
        return $result;
    }
    
    function update($query) {
        mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
    }
}
```

On `Dashboard.php` page when put this line of code for display user information `<?php require_once "Auth.php"; getUserInformation(); ?>` I wanted to display Welcome, `user_email`. But i get this error `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getUserInformation()` How should i edit my code to display user information ( user email or user name ). Any example code will be good.

Thanks all

Comment: We can't conclude this based on the function code alone. Please show the contents of Auth so that we can see the scope to which this function belongs.

Comment: Code is edited @El_Vanja

Comment: As I suspected, this function is part of a class. You can't access it directly like you would a regular, procedural-style function. You need to make an instance of the class and then call the function on it. See the manual on [OOP basics](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php), which shows an example of how classes are used.

Comment: Okay, i added this code ```$auth = new Auth(); $db_handle = new DBController();``` and get same error. Where i make mistake? Do i need to write ```$auth = new Auth(); $user = getUserInformation();``` or? @El_Vanja

Comment: You're still trying to call it procedurally. See example #2 in that link and how they call `$a->foo()`.

Comment: You will, however, have to supply some parameters to it. Because you defined it as taking two, but you aren't passing any.

Comment: Okay, I have a class named ```Auth``` and a function named ```getUserInformation``` on the dashboard.php page insert ```$auth = new getUserInformation(); $auth->getUserInformation();``` am i correct? @El_Vanja

Comment: No, `$auth = new Auth();` was right. Your class is not called `getUserInformation`, it's called `Auth`. As I said in the previous comment, you'll have to add parameters to your call: `$auth->getUserInformation(-- you need to place parameters in here --);`.

Comment: I got you now I need to define the variable $username, should I need to get from the database desire row or? @El_Vanja

Comment: Wherever you get username and mail from (I assume user input), take those values and pass them as parameters. If your `DbController` is set up correctly, it should yield the desired row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access methods in a class, you first need to initialize that class somewhere.

```php
$auth = new Auth;
```

Now you can access the public members and methods of that class.

```php
$auth->getUserInformation('username', 'email');
```

You can learn more by reading up on PHPs [classes and objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php), or by viewing the example I gave on an [3v4l demo page](https://3v4l.org/sVCN4).

Comment: I don't get user email in result